# why does my exception give a syntax error

Tags: django, django-views

well new to django and python the website i'm making is an ecommerce website and it has a carts app which deals with the shopping cart in the views.py file i have this function :

```
  def get(self, request):
    try:
        item_id = request.GET.get('item')
        quantity = request.GET.get('qty', 1)
        delete = request.GET.get('delete', 'n')
        cart, is_deleted, cart_item = self._process_cart(item_id, int(quantity), delete, request)
        cart_count = cart.total_count
        request.session['cart_count'] = cart_count
        return Response({'success': True,
         'deleted': is_deleted,
          'count': cart.count,
          'item_total': cart_item.item_total,
          'cart_price': cart.cart_price,
          'cart_count': cart_count}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as error:
        print error
```

it always gives an invalid syntax error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
 fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in 
 inner_run
 self.check(display_num_errors=True)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
 include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
 return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
 new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
 return check_resolver(resolver)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
 return check_method()
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 396, in check
 for pattern in self.url_patterns:
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
 res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
 patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
 res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
 return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
 32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in 
 _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\ecommerce-django-master\src\ecommerce\urls.py", line 15, in 
 <module>
 url(r'^cart/', include('carts.urls')),
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
 packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
 urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
 32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in 
 _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\ecommerce-django-master\src\carts\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
 from . import views
 File "C:\ecommerce-django-master\src\carts\views.py", line 56
return Response({'success': True, 'deleted': is_deleted, 'count': 
cart.count, 'item_total': cart_item.item_total, 'cart_price': 
cart.cart_price, 'cart_count':cart_count}, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so i tried using an if instead of try but the result was my shopping cart didn't work properly afterwards it never updated it's badge and never got anything in it even after an order

Comment: *it always gives a syntax error* - what error does it give?

Comment: place a full traceback here

Comment: Where does it indicate the invalid syntax is?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the syntax of the `return Response()` line. Make sure you have saved your code and restarted the server to make sure you are running the code you think you are. Your `print error` line *is* invalid, it should be `print(error)` in Python 3.

Comment: saved it still nothing changed

Comment: The error is based on your spacing it appears. I am uncertain how your spacing is in your code, but try placing your return Response on a single line and see if you have luck.

Comment: put it in a single line still no luck unfortunately

Comment: It seems that you are running Python 3. In Python 3, print is a function and no longer a statement. So, you'll have to do "print(error)". In Python 2, "print error" would have been fine.

Comment: i changed it to print(error) nothing changed